# How to add a package alias by monkey-patching

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm trying to work around a buggy package without modifying the source:

- A long subroutine in `Treex::PML::Schema::Container.pm` contains two references to the non-existent package `Treex::PML::FSFactory`. It should be `Treex::PML::Factory`.
- The offending subroutine is too long to copy and monkey-patch from another file, so I'd like to monkey-patch `Treex::PML` so that it offers `Treex::PML::FSFactory` as an alias for `Treex::PML::Factory`.

In my main program I tried the following (based on [this recipe](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=823772)), but it doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
use Treex::PML;
package Treex::PML;
use Package::Alias FSFactory => 'Treex::PML::Factory';

package MyPackage;
...
```

How can I get `Treex::PML::FSFactory` to spring into existence, in such a way that it is visible to `Treex::PML::Schema::Container`?

**Edit:** This particular bug was fixed within hours of my bug report! But it's useful to know how to alias packages anyway. Although I solved my problem by subclassing, as the accepted answer recommends, I've added a self-answer showing how it can be done with aliases.

Comment: Why don't you file a bug report? I suspect the author is @choroba, an active member of the community.

Comment: I will do that too, thanks. CTAN was telling me the author was Petr Pajas, whom I've contacted recently about related isssues (the application I'm wrestling with)-- no response. But I see now that google had sent me to an older version of PML. @choroba has taken it over.

Comment: Does your original attempt work if you do it *before* the use Treex::PML?

Comment: `use` takes effect before anything else in the script, so that couldn't make any difference. But actually my code was breaking due to an unrelated problem. Aliasing works fine (even without the `Alias` module), see my self-answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the references in question,

```
$content = Treex::PML::FSFactory->createSeq(...)
$content = Treex::PML::FSFactory->createList(...)
```

Adding the following should be sufficient:

```
{
   package Treex::PML::FSFactory;
   our @ISA = qw( Treex::PML::Factory );
}
```

I checked if `Treex::PML::Factory::createSeq` and `Treex::PML::Factory::createList` mind being called via a subclass, and they don't; they completely ignore their invocant.

Comment: Thanks, good idea but it didn't work. Any idea why? I'm guessing that the definition of `FSFactory` is not visible from inside `Container::validate_object()`, but I don't know anything about the semantics of perl namespaces-- I could be wrong. I don't know if it's relevant but I have a separate instance of `use Treex::PML;` in the code (needed elsewhere).

Comment: Packages exist globally. It's not a visibility issue. It could be a timing issue. You may have done the assignment too late. You may even need a `BEGIN`. Easy to check by adding a `print` next to the assignment to `@ISA`.

Comment: Could you explain what I must pay attention to in order to get the timing right? The code is in the same file (and well above) the subroutine that calls the buggy function in Container.

Comment: You need to assign to `Treex::PML::FSFactory`'s `@ISA` before `validate_object` calls methods from `Treex::PML::FSFactory`.

Comment: I monkey-patched a different buggy subroutine (Treex::PML::Node::validate_subtree) in the same place in my code, and it worked correctly.

Comment: Well, the file with the attempted patch is read on start-up, and the validation happens interactively on request-- so certainly later. It's an extension module for a large GUI application, so it's not easy to isolate it. If I get it to work in isolation (in a test file), I'll still be at a loss as to what is interfering here.

Comment: I mentioned how to check in my first comment. What happens first, the error or the print?

Comment: Ok, thanks!  I'm inserting diagnostics to try to follow the flow of control. I'll be back when I know more.

Comment: It worked! There was a framework problem getting in the way. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

@ikegami's suggestion, to derive a class instead of aliasing, worked well. But here is also how to alias one package name to another, as the question asks:

a. With `Package::Alias`:

```
use Package::Alias 'Treex::PML::FSFactory' => 'Treex::PML::Factory';
```

b. To avoid downloading `Package::Alias` from cpan, I followed [this recipe](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=882717) which shows how `Package::Alias` actually does it. It worked :-)

```
*Treex::PML::FSFactory:: = \*Treex::PML::Factory::;
```